# Changing a color of a button that is located in imported UserControl block

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im trying to desing a plugin for a engineering software using their API.
They have predefined `UserControl` blocks to help people with programming tools for their software.
Im trying to change the colour of foreground and text colour of said `UserControl` button, but haven't had any luck yet.
My knowledge in WPF or programming as a whole is limited, so haven't tried any fancy stuff.

[image: The picture of UI]

So my question is: Is there an easy way to change the colours of objects inside UserControl blocks?

```
<tsd:PluginWindowBase
    x:Class="MyFirstPlugin.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyFirstPlugin"
    xmlns:UIControls="clr-namespace:Tekla.Structures.Dialog.UIControls;assembly=Tekla.Structures.Dialog"
    xmlns:dialog="clr-namespace:Tekla.Structures.Dialog;assembly=Tekla.Structures.Dialog"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:tsd="clr-namespace:Tekla.Structures.Dialog;assembly=Tekla.Structures.Dialog"
    Title="{tsd:Loc albl_Title_Plugin}" Height="500" 
    Width="800" 
    MinWidth="600"
    MinHeight="400">
<Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <UIControls:WpfSaveLoad 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
    />
    <UIControls:WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
    </UIControls:WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel>
    <Button 
        Margin="10,53,29,369">

    </Button>

</Grid>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tekla.Structures.Dialog.UIControls.WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tekla.Structures.Dialog.UIControls">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="363*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="194*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="false" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <Button Click="ok_Click" x:Name="okButton" Content="albl_OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
      <Button Click="apply_Click" x:Name="applyButton" Content="albl_Apply" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
      <Button Click="modify_Click" x:Name="modifyButton" Content="albl_Modify" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
      <Button Click="get_Click" x:Name="getButton" Content="albl_Get" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
      <Button Click="onoff_Click" x:Name="toggleButton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Control.Background>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="Onoff.png"/>
        </Control.Background>
      </Button>
      <Button Click="cancel_Click" x:Name="cancelButton" Content="albl_Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: add property to your UserControl. use that property to change button color (e.g. via binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the the `Foreground` color on the `UserContol` itself, but that will not apply to all controls inside.

```
<UIControls:WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel Foreground="Red"/>
```

For those controls that do not apply it, you can use a relative source binding to refer to `Foreground`.

```
<Button x:Name="okButton" Content="albl_OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel}}}"/>
```

If you intend to have multiple different foreground colors in your `UserControl`, like for your buttons specifically, you can always declare custom dependency properties in your control, e.g.:

```
public partial class WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel : UserControl
{
   // ...constructor, other code.

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(ButtonForeground), typeof(Brush), typeof(WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

   public Brush ButtonForeground
   {
      get => (Brush)GetValue(ButtonForegroundProperty);
      set => SetValue(ButtonForegroundProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Bind the `Foreground` property of the target control like above using a relative source binding.

```
<Button x:Name="okButton" Content="albl_OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        Foreground="{Binding ButtonForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel}}}"/>
```

Then you can assign the foreground color for your buttons directly, bind it or create a style.

```
<local:WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel ButtonForeground="Red"/>
```

---

An alternative to the `RelativeSource` bindings above is to assign a name to your `UserControl` and use an `ElementName` binding instead, which is less verbose here.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tekla.Structures.Dialog.UIControls.WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancel"
             ...
             x:Name="WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancelInstance">
```

```
<Button x:Name="okButton" Content="albl_OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="200" Height="26" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        Foreground="{Binding ButtonForeground, ElementName=WpfOkApplyModifyGetOnOffCancelInstance}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Content="Hello" Foreground="Black"/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

To change the background, use the `Background` property.
For example:

```
<Button Content="Hello" Background="Black"/>
```

Comment: This works for regular buttons but not for buttons in the UserControl block.